# Laravel Policies not stopping delete action

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have just started using **Policies** within **Laravel 5.4** to handle my authorization. I have been following the official documentation and created a PostPolicy.

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class PostPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function delete(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        return false;
        //return $user->id === $post->user_id;
    }
}
```

My goal is to **stop the ability to delete a post** using Policies.
I am currently still able to delete and cannot find a way to implement these Policy rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to authorize actions. For example, you could do that:

```
if ($user->can('delete', $post)) {
```

Or in controller:

```
$this->authorize('delete', $post);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#authorizing-actions-using-policies

Comment: For your first suggestion, which model do I add the code to?
I tried placing it in the User model, however it throws an error.
I'm unable to make out where it should go based on the documentation.

Comment: @Roo you usually want to do that in a controller method.